# Converting curl to HtttClient request

Tags: c#, curl, httpclient

Im trying to do this curl request (from API documentation) in HttpClient:
Please not that the code below is just copied from their documentation and does not contain any of my information.

POST /oauth/token (get access token)

```
   $ curl -v -X POST https://api.tink.com/api/v1/oauth/token \
   -d 'code=1a513b99126ade1e7718135019fd119a' \
   -d 'client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID' \
   -d 'client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET' \
   -d 'grant_type=authorization_code'

   {
       "access_token": "78b0525677c7414e8b202c48be57f3da",
       "token_type": "bearer",
       "expires_in": 7200,
       "refresh_token": "33f10ce3cb1941b8a274af53da03f361",
       "scope": "accounts:read,statistics:read,transactions:read,user:read"
   }
```

I've tried to make a post request to the oauth/token endpoint both with all the information requested as header (with an empty body) and as a json document (with and without the headers). 
When I only have the information in the headers I get a 401 back, but I've verified that all the data is correct. All other ways that I've tried has generated a 400.

As far as I can understand the json below the curl is the response, but Im not accustomed at all to curl.

Comment: Show a link to the docs, and also the code you have tried so far that is not working. Let's see if we spot the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a handy site here: https://curl.olsh.me/

I wouldn't recommend sending secrets over the web, so be sure to anonymise the values first and translate them back after.

So for the command you've pasted you'd get:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://api.tink.com/api/v1/oauth/token"))
    {
        var contentList = new List<string>();
        contentList.Add("code=1a513b99126ade1e7718135019fd119a");
        contentList.Add("client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID");
        contentList.Add("client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET");
        contentList.Add("grant_type=authorization_code");
        request.Content = new StringContent(string.Join("&", contentList));
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 

        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    }
}
```

The 401 headers you are getting back may be due to passing in the wrong id and secret, I presume there is a way for you to get test credentials.

Comment: This is a neat tool, however HttpClient shouldn't be in a using statement. Noted in the tool's issues. https://github.com/olsh/curl-to-csharp/issues/6

Comment: I agree, I'll leave it until the tool is updated. Giving it an upvote though, thanks for the info 

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Wierd way of sending credentials imho though.